# Why does the java.util.Objects.checkIndex method need @ForceInline?

Tags: java, java-9

**Java version**: [openjdk-18.0.2.1](https://jdk.java.net/18/)

```java
@ForceInline
public static int checkIndex(int index, int length) {
    return Preconditions.checkIndex(index, length, null);
}
```

I'm not sure why the class `java.util.Objects` needs an annotation applied to the `checkIndex` method. (added in java9 version)

After a brief investigation, I think it was used in the case of `it may act as a temporary workaround until the profiling and lining perfected by the HotSpot VM is successfully improved.` Is that correct?

Additionally, I wonder if the similar methods `checkFromToIndex` and `checkFromIndexSize` are not annotated.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Why do you care? And why do you tag your question with “Java 9” when you’re referring to Java 18?